# Undo a directory remove in HAMMER, DragonFly BSD

Tags: filesystems, undo, rm, hammer, dragonfly-bsd

In DragonFly BSD, you have the neat functionality of transaction history for all files, which you can inspect using `undo -a <filename>`. If you remove a file you can bring it back to life using `undo -o <output_filename> <removed_file>`. Is there any similar functionality if you happen to remove a directory? Like `undo <dir>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there isn't. You just need to cd into the transaction id (cd @@0x..) and copying over the stuff.

Another option is using Slider (https://github.com/jrmarino/Slider).

Cheers,

Antonio Huete